# Area between two given equations

Tags: calculus, analysis, area

Let $x^2 + y^2$ = 6 and $x = y^2$. What is the area between them?

I solved the two equations in terms of y and I graph it in Geogebra: https://www.geogebra.org/classic/ahnk4hfw

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Solving the two equations in terms of x, the graph is:
https://www.geogebra.org/classic/nwznqk3c

When I integrate in terms of y (the graph is the first one), the bounds are -$\sqrt 2$ and $\sqrt 2$. The integrand is $ \sqrt {6-y^2} $ - $y^2$. I got 4.63 as the area.
$$\int_{-\sqrt 2}^{\sqrt 2} \sqrt {6-y^2} - y^2 \, dy = 4.63 $$
Although, I am not sure if I expressed the integral correctly because it seems that I am missing one function: the -$\sqrt {6-y^2} $.

When I follow the second graph, isn't it that the whole region is bounded by the two functions, and hence the area is the circle's area? Or should I only choose the positive square roots and not the negative ones?

My last question is, what is the best approach of finding the integral of this case? Is it by integrating with respect to y or x? Do I only need to take the smaller region?

Answer (score 1):

Using $\int ydx$.

These curves intersect at $P_1(2,\sqrt{2}),$ and $P_2(2,-\sqrt{2})$

$$A=2\left[\int_{0}^{2} \sqrt{x} dx+\int_{2}^{\sqrt{6}} \sqrt{6-x^2} dx\right]$$
$$A=\frac{8\sqrt{2}}{3}+[3\pi-2\sqrt{2}-6 \sin^{-1}\sqrt{2/3}]=4.5356$$

Comment: How about if I take the area of the smaller region and add it to the area of the larger region to have the total area 'bounded by the two equations given'? Or should I only take the area of one region even though it is not specified in the problem which region I should solved for? Thank you! And I notice that when I solve the equations in terms of y, its graph is different compared with the graph of functions in terms of x. Can you explain this? Because the first graph states that there is only one region; the second says there are two.

Comment: Because the problem is just I should solve the area of the region bounded by the 2 equations

Comment: But I am unsure which graph I should use in defending my answer.

Comment: There are always two methods for the calculation of the same areaone is $\int_{x_1}^{x_2}  y dx$ and the other one is $\int_{y_1}^{y_2} x dy$. For example area made by $y=x-x^2$ on $x$-axis it is $A=\int_{0}^{1} x(1-x) dx$. Next $x^2-x+y=0 \implies x_{1,2}=\frac{1\pm \sqrt{1-4y}}{2}$. So $A=\int_{0}^{1/4} [ x_1-x_2] dy=\int_{0}^{1/4} \sqrt{1-4y} dy$ both integral give $A=1/6$.

Answer (score 1):

The framing of the question makes it clear that the proposer has not realized there are two regions bounded by the given curves.  The safest choice (showing knowledge and mastery of the material) is to compute both areas in detail.

We plot the equations to understand the region in question.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The two curves partition the plane into four regions.  Two are unbounded.  Two are bounded, labelled $A$ and $B$.  $A$ has both curves on its boundary and $B$ has both curves on its boundary.  Therefore, both $A$ and $B$ meet the specification "Let $x^2+y^2 = 6$ and $x=y^2$. What is the area between them?"

Region $A$ is [horizontally simple](https://people.math.osu.edu/mcginnis.7/11Wi%20M254/M254%20Ch14.pdf), with $y \in [-\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2}]$ bounded to the right by $x = \sqrt{6 - y^2}$ and to the left by $x = y^2$.  The area of $A$ is \begin{align*}
A &= \int_{-\sqrt{2}}^{\sqrt{2}} \; \left(\sqrt{6 - y^2}\right) - \left(y^2\right) \,\mathrm{d}y  \\
    &= \int_{-\sqrt{2}}^{\sqrt{2}} \; \sqrt{6 - y^2} \,\mathrm{d}y - \left. \frac{y^3}{3} \right|_{y=-\sqrt{2}}^{\sqrt{2}}  \\
    &= \int_{-\sqrt{2}}^{\sqrt{2}} \; \sqrt{6 - y^2} \,\mathrm{d}y  \\
    &\quad {}- \left( \left( \frac{(\sqrt{2})^3}{3} \right) - \left( \frac{(-\sqrt{2})^3}{3} \right)  \right)  \\
    &= \int_{-\sqrt{2}}^{\sqrt{2}} \; \sqrt{6 - y^2} \,\mathrm{d}y - \frac{2 \sqrt{2}}{3}  \\
    & \qquad \begin{bmatrix}
        y = \sqrt{6} \sin \theta  &  \theta(\sqrt{2}) = \sin^{-1}(\sqrt{2}/\sqrt{6}) = \sin^{-1}(1/\sqrt{3})  \\
        \mathrm{d}y = \sqrt{6} \cos \theta \,\mathrm{d}\theta  &  \theta(-\sqrt{2}) = \sin^{-1}(-\sqrt{2}/\sqrt{6}) = \sin^{-1}(-1/\sqrt{3})
\end{bmatrix}  \\
    &= \int_{\sin^{-1}(-1/\sqrt{3})}^{\sin^{-1}(1/\sqrt{3})} \; \sqrt{6 - 6 \sin^2 \theta} \sqrt{6} \cos \theta \,\mathrm{d}\theta - \frac{2 \sqrt{2}}{3}  \\
    &= 6 \int_{\sin^{-1}(-1/\sqrt{3})}^{\sin^{-1}(1/\sqrt{3})} \; \sqrt{1 - \sin^2 \theta} \cos \theta \,\mathrm{d}\theta - \frac{2 \sqrt{2}}{3}  \\
    &= 6 \int_{\sin^{-1}(-1/\sqrt{3})}^{\sin^{-1}(1/\sqrt{3})} \; |\cos \theta| \cos \theta \,\mathrm{d}\theta - \frac{2 \sqrt{2}}{3}  \\
\end{align*}
Since the range of arcsine is $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ and cosine is nonnegative on that interval, so $|\cos \theta| = \cos \theta$ in this integral.
\begin{align*}
A &= 6 \int_{\sin^{-1}(-1/\sqrt{3})}^{\sin^{-1}(1/\sqrt{3})} \; \cos^2 \theta \,\mathrm{d}\theta - \frac{2 \sqrt{2}}{3}  \\
    &= 6 \left( \left( \frac{2(\sin^{-1}(1/\sqrt{3})) + \sin(2(\sin^{-1}(1/\sqrt{3})))}{4} \right) - \left( \frac{2(\sin^{-1}(-1/\sqrt{3})) + \sin(2(\sin^{-1}(-1/\sqrt{3})))}{4} \right) \right) - \frac{2 \sqrt{2}}{3}
\end{align*}
Now for $-\pi/2 \leq r \leq \pi/2$, \begin{align*}
\sin(2 \sin^{-1}(r)) &= 2 \sin\sin^{-1}(r) \cos \sin^{-1}(r)  \\
    &= 2 r \sqrt{1-r^2}  \text{,}
\end{align*}
so
$$  \sin(2 \sin^{-1}(1/\sqrt{3})) = 2 \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \sqrt{ \frac{2}{3} } = \frac{2\sqrt{2}}{3} $$
and
$$  \sin(2 \sin^{-1}(-1/\sqrt{3})) = -2 \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \sqrt{ \frac{2}{3} } = \frac{-2\sqrt{2}}{3}  \text{.}  $$
Continuing,
\begin{align*}
A &= 6 \left( \left( \frac{2(\sin^{-1}(1/\sqrt{3})) + \frac{2\sqrt{2}}{3}}{4} \right) - \left( \frac{2(\sin^{-1}(-1/\sqrt{3})) + \frac{-2\sqrt{2}}{3}}{4} \right) \right) - \frac{2 \sqrt{2}}{3}  \\
    &= 6 \left( \left( \frac{2(\sin^{-1}(1/\sqrt{3})) + \frac{2\sqrt{2}}{3}}{4} \right) - \left( \frac{-2(\sin^{-1}(1/\sqrt{3})) + \frac{-2\sqrt{2}}{3}}{4} \right) \right) - \frac{2 \sqrt{2}}{3}  \\
    &= 6 \left(\frac{4(\sin^{-1}(1/\sqrt{3})) + 4\frac{\sqrt{2}}{3}}{4} \right) - \frac{2 \sqrt{2}}{3}  \\
    &= 6 \left(\sin^{-1}\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \right) + \frac{\sqrt{2}}{3} \right) - \frac{2 \sqrt{2}}{3}  \\
    &= 6 \sin^{-1}\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \right) + \frac{4\sqrt{2}}{3}  \\
    &= 4.635\,687\,293\,604\,387\,412{\dots} \text{.}
\end{align*}

The region $B$ is neither horizontally simple nor vertically simple.  However, it is the disk of radius $\sqrt{6}$ with region $A$ removed, so its area is
\begin{align*}
B &= \pi (\sqrt{6})^2 - A  \\
    &= 6 \pi - \left( 6 \sin^{-1}\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \right) + \frac{4\sqrt{2}}{3} \right)    \\
    &= 14.213\,868\,627\,934\,372\,018{\dots}  \text{.}  
\end{align*}

The sum of the areas of regions $A$ and $B$ is that of the disk of radius $\sqrt{6}$, which is $6 \pi$.

[ Alternatively, we can decompose region $B$ into three vertically simple regions:

- the left half-disk on $[-\sqrt{6},0]$ bounded above by $\sqrt{6 - x^2}$ and below by $-\sqrt{6 - x^2}$,
- the portion in quadrant I, on $[0,2]$ bounded above by $\sqrt{6-x^2}$ and below by $\sqrt{x}$, and
- the portion in quadrant II, on $[0,2]$ bounded above by $-\sqrt{x}$ and below by $-\sqrt{6-x^2}$.

These last two regions are equal by symmetry, so maybe we avoid evaluating one of them. ]

[ Alternatively, we can decompose region $B$ into
three horizontally simple regions

- on $[-\sqrt{6}, -\sqrt{2}]$ right bounded by $\sqrt{6-y^2}$ and left bounded by $-\sqrt{6-y^2}$,
- on $[-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2}]$, right bounded by $y^2$ and left bounded by $-\sqrt{6-y^2}$, and
- on $[\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{6}]$, right bounded by $\sqrt{6-y^2}$ and left bounded by $-\sqrt{6-y^2}$.

The first and third of these regions have the same area by symmetry so maybe we avoid evaluating one of them. ]

Comment: Thanks for this! By the way, I got the same area for the smaller region.. did I write the correct integral form of it?

Comment: @JordanG : Except for the false "${}=4.63$", the integral in your Question matches my first "$A = {}$ [an integral]" line.

Answer (score 0):

$x^2+y^2=6$ and $y^2=x$ intersect at $P_2(2,\sqrt{2}),$ and $P_1(2,-\sqrt{2})$. The area included between them is best given by
$$A=\int_{-\sqrt{2}}^{\sqrt{2}} [\sqrt{6-y^2}-y^2] dy= \left[\frac{y}{2}\sqrt{6-y^2}+3\sinh^{-1}(y/\sqrt{6})-\frac{y^3}{3}\right]_{-\sqrt{2}}^{\sqrt{2}}$$
$$A=\frac{2}{3}[\sqrt{2}+9\sin^{-1}(1/\sqrt{3})]=4.6354$$

**Note**:Here area projected on $y$-axis is a good idea. So $A=\int_{y_1}^{y_2}[x_1(y)-x_2(y)]dy.$

Comment: The parabola partitions the disk bounded by the circle into two regions.  This integral is the area of one of the regions.  Why did you reject the other region?

Comment: That is one way. But this one is simpler. Integral of the upper curve - lower curve on $y$ axis in terms of $y$ from $y_1$ to $y_2$. Use $\int x dy$, instead of $\int y dx$.

Comment: There are two regions bounded by the given curves.  You have ignored the larger region.  Why?  I've added a diagram to the Question to clarify the ambiguity in the problem statement.

Comment: Every thing has been taken care of here. Look into your book this must be the answer.

Comment: Sorry there was a little problem in the final answer, I have corrected it now, please see..

Answer (score 0):

There are actually two possible regions:

[image]

Or,

[image]

You see, the 'area between circle and parabola' is a bit ambiguous without saying which area specifically. But I'll take a guess that you are referring the orange (i.e: 2nd diagram). For computing the area, the y axis method and x axis method are both equivalents. Let's focus on the area in first quadrant for now because you can find the one in fourth by symmetry,

[image: ![enter image description here]

Using integration with x-axis, the area is given as:

$$ \int_0^2 y_{parabola} dx + \int_2^{\sqrt{6}} y_{circle} dx$$

If you had done integration with $y$,

$$ \int_0^{\sqrt{2} } (x_{circle} - x_{parabola})  dy$$

Perhaps the second integral is easier because you're evaluating over the same bounds.

Comment: How about if the problem is 'find the area of the region bounded by these two give equations'? Does that mean I must take the area of the whole circle?

Comment: Well the blue area is also the one 'bounded' between the two equations and so is the other orange. How did you conclude that you must take the area of whole circle

Comment: Because if I take the area of the orange + the area of the blue = Area of the circle?

Comment: Or is my theory that we can combine the two regions bounded by a circle and parabola wrong?

Comment: Well I guess that's a way of looking at It but I think ti's best to shade out the area and show what you mean specifically other than to be ambiguous. For an actual real life application, you'd probably be more explicit on which the area you want is